# Looking to mix 2 things together to equal 100%

Tags: ratio

I need to find 100%. Let's say I am mixing sugar and flour. How many grams of sugar would 100g of flour need?

I want the 100g of flour to make up 40% of the mixture.

How many grams of sugar will I need for the remaining 60%?

Comment: Are you basically asking the amount of sugar in a 60:40 sugar:flour ratio if there is 100 grams of flour?

Comment: It might seem nit picky, but learning how to phrase the question correctly would likely help in learning how to answer future, similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a proportion for this.  $$\frac{100g}{x}=\frac{40%}{60%}$$  Solve and we have $$x=150$$  So, you need 150 grams of sugar in this mixture.